# Output not showing

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, c++14, stdvector

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define endl "\n"
#define ll long long

int
main ()
{ 
   ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false);
   cin.tie (NULL);
   ll n;
   cin >> n;
   vector < ll > v (n);
   for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      cin >> v[i];
   }
   ll c1, c2, c3;
   vector < ll > neg, pos, z;
   for (ll i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (v[i] == 0)
    {
      c3++;
      z.push_back (v[i]);
    }
    else if (v[i] < 0)
    {
      c1++;
      neg.push_back (v[i]);
    }
    else if (v[i] > 0)
    {
      c2++;
      pos.push_back (v[i]);
    }
 }
 ll neg_num = neg[c1 - 1];
 if (c1 % 2 == 0)
 {
     neg.pop_back ();
     c1--;
     z.push_back (neg_num);
     c3++;
 } 
 cout << c1 << " ";
 for (ll i = 0; i < c1; i++)
 {
     cout << neg[i] << " ";
 }
 cout << endl;
 cout << c2 << " ";
 for (ll i = 0; i < c2; i++)
 {
    cout << pos[i] << " ";
 }
 cout << endl;
 cout << c3 << " ";
 for (ll i = 0; i < c3; i++)
 {
    cout << z[i] << " ";
 }
}
```

So the above code I have tried for CodeForces Problem 300A , I am not sure whether its correct or not but this code is not giving any output to the screen so what is the problem, and exactly due to which reason this is happening?

If anyone having good solution to that problem please share

Comment: `c1, c2, c3;` are all uninitialized.

Comment: Don't make code hard to read with `ll` as an alias for `long long`. Useless abbreviations only make the code hard to read without giving any real benefit.

Comment: Will definitely keep that in mind, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's one problem:

```
 ll c1, c2, c3;
```

... You declare three variables but never assign any value to them.  Reading any of those uninitialized values (e.g. when you increment or decrement them) will invoke undefined behavior, as there is no telling what value they currently have.

Here's a second problem:

```
ll neg_num = neg[c1 - 1];
```

If `c1` is less than `1` or greater than `neg.size()`, then `neg[c1 - 1]` will try to read a value from an invalid index in the vector `neg` and that will also invoke undefined behavior (it shows up as a Segmentation fault on my machine, but undefined behavior can cause anything to happen so don't rely on that to detect it)

A few other style-issues:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

Don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`; it's not an official header and including it makes your code non-portable since that header file is not guaranteed to exist.  Include the official headers for the feature you want to use, instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

Also, you shouldn't do this:

```
#define endl "\n"
#define ll long long
```

Using `#define` to make up your own keywords is bad practice as the C++ preprocessor is a crude mechanism and error-prone to use.  If you must define your own type-names, do it with `typedef` or `using` instead:

```
typedef long long ll;   // works in all versions of C++

using ll = long long;   // works in C++11 or later
```

Finally, this is unnecessary anyway:

```
#define endl "\n"
```

... since [std::endl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is already defined for you, and you have a `using namespace std;` directive so you can already refer to it as just `endl`.

Comment: hey I have resolved the issues you have raised like not initializing the values to c1,c2,c3 ,I have initialized it to 0 and removed #define endl "\n" line but code seems to be not working now also, Its giving an **error** of terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc, can you provide a reason and solution to question [link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/300/A) in C++

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/